# AWS EKS Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage

Tags: kubernetes

I have a K8s cluster via AWS EKS. I have a set of nodes which are m5.xlarge backed by an EBS volume (100gb)

I have a pod which occasionally runs that does "something" and then k8s reports the following error:

```
v1/nodes error
Error Occurred in Node: ip-10-0-1-54.us-east-2.compute.internal in prod-k8s cluster
Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage

v1/pods error
Error Occurred in Pod: actions-runner-system/github-runner-jnp9m-2rwsr in prod-k8s cluster
The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container docker was using 80Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. Container runner was using 84096Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. 

Error Occurred in Node: ip-10-0-1-54.us-east-2.compute.internal in prod-k8s cluster
failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Wanted to free 11069618585 bytes, but freed 0 bytes
```

Why is my node evicting this pod?

What is ephemeral-storage in this context?

What can i do here to prevent this from happening?

Comment: It's being evicted because it's using ephemeral-storage. I know that isn't very helpful, but ephemeral storage is basically any storage that containers use which isn't reserved using a Persistent Volume or otherwise. 

For example, a container that downloads files internally to `/temp` where no PV exists is using ephemeral storage. It's called that because the data does not exist beyond the pod lifecycle.

Comment: The last error, failed garbage collection, occurs when the node attempts to free space by removing unused docker images. This error is usually triggered when that fails, usually because all images on the machine are in use.

To remedy, you can increase the size of the EBS volumes, decrease the size and/or number of container images on each node, or determine why so much ephemeral storage is being used.